# Which, if any, appearances of the Tick were hallucinations?

Tags: the-tick

In *The Tick* (2017), everyperson Arthur occasionally sees a  blue-suited hero called the Tick. We know that at least some scenes with the Tick are real (probably the majority), because the Tick does things like throw gangsters through walls, blow up buildings, and other such fun. Also, people like Ms. Lint and Dot see him.

On the other hand, Arthur also has visual and auditory hallucinations, and we are occasionally treated to scenes from the point of view of other people where he is talking to thin air, believing he is talking to the Tick. It’s also possible that the Tick has some power to disappear, though.

Which scenes where Arthur interacts with the Tick, if any, are hallucinations?

Answer (score 2):

Arthur is totally sane. He does not hallucinate. None of the appearances of the Tick in the show are hallucinations.

The idea that he is insane is based on his belief that the Terror is still alive and that there is some great conspiracy theory surrounding this.

> However the entire point of the first season is that the Terror is, infact, alive, and Arthur is not really insane after all.

In the first few episodes, we (the viewer) are thrown a 'false flag' where Arthur assumes that he is hallucinating. But, this is quickly debunked as Dot, an erstwhile normal person, can see the Tick as well. The rest of the two seasons of the show does not revisit this point. The Tick is consistently shown to be a real person, and everyone else treats him as such. He never manifests any powers of invisibility or anything similar.

By the last episodes of the second season, Arthur's mother apologizes for having mistreated him by assuming that he was mentally ill or hallucinating.